Preventing Updates on Records with is_deleted = false Causes Error When Setting is_deleted to True
enter image description here
const { error } = await supabase
      .from("people")
      .update({ is_deleted: true })
      .eq("id", person.id);

new row violates row-level security policy for table "people
enter image description here
I used FOR ALL with USING (is_deleted = false) to exclude records where is_deleted is true from select queries and prevent updates. However, I'm encountering an error when trying to update the is_deleted status from false to true.

As you've stated your policy states that you cannot update if is_deleted is not false. You need to revisit your policy.
